# How to create new dropdown's depending on the choice in the previous dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a jQuery that allows new dropdowns to appear depending on the choice of an initial dropdown. Example:

Dropdown 1 has the options: Car, Airplane. If I select Car a new dropdown will appear with the options: BMW, Audi, Tesla.

If Airplane is selected the next drop down will instead show: Airbus, Boeing.

If I select BMW in the second dropdown (Car->BMW) a third dropdown will show options like M3, M5 and so on (this is just examples for you to understand my problem). Basically I just want new dropdowns to appear depending on the choice of the previous one.

I tried something on my own like this:

```
HTML:
<form id="test" name="testSearch">
<select class="test1">
  <option value="option">Car</option>
  <option value="country">Airplane</option>
</select>

jQuery:
$('form[name="testSearch"] select').click(function () {
        $('div[name=carForm]').append('<select id="carBrand">'+
        '<option>BMW</option>'+
         '<option>Audi</option>'+
         '<option>Tesla</option>'+
```

This is not however not nice, I saw that it is possible to create div's with dropdowns and then make them visible depending on what choice you make in the previous dropdown. I think that is the way to go?

Sorry for no jsfiddle btw. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: What you're describing is often referred to as **cascading dropdowns**. If you search something like *"jQuery cascading dropdowns"*, you'll probably have some better luck finding a good solution.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks for pointing out how they are refered to as. I have however had a hard time to find how to create dropdowns that appear after each other depending on the choice, allowing to scale into more and more choices after each other: Car -> BMW -> M5 -> 2017. Or Airplane -> Airbus -> A320 -> White. All this new dropdowns depending on choice before, that appears after being hidden first (divs) (sorry for the bad examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing you a vague answer, but then ended up expanding on it so much that I made a full working example. I'll explain it all below, with some additional documentation linked at the very bottom.

```js
var dropdowns = [
  {
    type: "Vehicle",
    options: ["Car", "Airplane"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Vehicle",
    parentOption: "Car",
    type: "Make",
    options: ["Audi", "BMW"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Vehicle",
    parentOption: "Airplane",
    type: "Type",
    options: ["737", "747"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Make",
    parentOption: "Audi",
    type: "Model",
    options: ["A4", "A8L"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Make",
    parentOption: "BMW",
    type: "Model",
    options: ["M3", "M5"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Make",
    type: "Color",
    options: ["White", "Black", "Red"]
  }
];

function refreshDropdowns(parentType, selection, $container) {
  var $newContainer = $("<div class='container' />");

  if ($container)
    $container.append($newContainer);
  else
    $("body").append($newContainer);

  dropdowns
    .filter(i => i.parentType === parentType && (i.parentOption === selection || !i.parentOption))
    .map(i => {
      var $newDropdown = $("<select />").data("type", i.type);
      var $options = i.options.map(option => $("<option>").val(option).text(option));
      var $placeholderOption = $("<option>").text(`Select ${i.type}...`);
      $newDropdown
        .append($placeholderOption)
        .append($options);
      return $newDropdown;
    })
    .forEach($i => {
      if ($container) $newContainer.append($i)
      else {
        var $rootContainer = $("<div class='container' />");
        $rootContainer.appendTo($newContainer).append($i);
      }
    });
}

$(document).on("change", "select", function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest(".container");
  var type = $(this).data("type");
  var selection = $(this).val();

  $container.find(".container").remove();
  refreshDropdowns(type, selection, $container);
});

refreshDropdowns();
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.root-container {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**1. Create a structure/list for your dropdowns**

In my example, each has a `type`, an optional `parentType` (anything without a parentType is assumed to be always visible), and an optional specific `parentOption`. For example, the `Model` dropdown with `M3` and `M5` requires "BMW" to be selected for the `Make`. If you look at the object, this should make more sense.

This is extremely beneficial because now you can control everything from here, rather than diving into the code each time you want to update things.

```
var dropdowns = [
  {
    type: "Vehicle",
    options: ["Car", "Airplane"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Vehicle",
    parentOption: "Car",
    type: "Make",
    options: ["Audi", "BMW"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Vehicle",
    parentOption: "Airplane",
    type: "Type",
    options: ["737", "747"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Make",
    parentOption: "Audi",
    type: "Model",
    options: ["A4", "A8L"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Make",
    parentOption: "BMW",
    type: "Model",
    options: ["M3", "M5"]
  },
  {
    parentType: "Make",
    type: "Color",
    options: ["White", "Black", "Red"]
  }
];
```

**2. Use that structure to determine which dropdowns to add/remove when selections change**

```
function refreshDropdowns(parentType, selection, $container) {
  //All our new dropdowns should go in a container together.
  //This makes it easier to remove all children later on.
  var $newContainer = $("<div class='container' />");
  if ($container)
    $container.append($newContainer);
  else
    $("body").append($newContainer);

  //From our dropdown list, find any that depend on this dropdown and/or option
  dropdowns
    .filter(i => i.parentType === parentType && (i.parentOption === selection || !i.parentOption))

    //Now that we know which dropdowns we need to create, let's create the actual
    //<select> and <option> elements
    .map(i => {
      var $newDropdown = $("<select />").data("type", i.type);
      var $options = i.options.map(option => $("<option>").val(option).text(option));
      var $placeholderOption = $("<option>").text(`Select ${i.type}...`);
      $newDropdown
        .append($placeholderOption)
        .append($options);
      return $newDropdown;
    })

    //Add them all to the container. For root-level dropdowns, we'll need separate containers.
    .forEach($i => {
      if ($container) $newContainer.append($i)
      else {
        var $rootContainer = $("<div class='container' />");
        $rootContainer.appendTo($newContainer).append($i);
      }
    });
}
```

**3. Call our function whenever a dropdown changes**

```
//We use event delegation here to trigger events for dynamic elements
$(document).on("change", "select", function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest(".container");
  var type = $(this).data("type");
  var selection = $(this).val();

  //Remove any dropdowns that depend on this one
  $container.find(".container").remove();
  refreshDropdowns(type, selection, $container);
});
```

**4. Call our function once on page-load just to create the root/parentless dropdowns**

```
refreshDropdowns();
```

---

[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me, it's exactly how I wanted it. The comments are great for me to learn what is going on. Btw, is it possible to give the selects an id? Like: id="vehicle" and also add value to the option such as value="BMW"?

Once again thank you!

Comment: On the line where the dropdown is created (`var $newDropdown`), you can add `.attr("id", i.type)` to assign the id. The options should already have the value, unless I've made a mistake!

Comment: Just confirmed, the options do in fact have the value. However, if you needed an ID that was different than the text, you could make your options be an array of objects instead of an array of strings. The objects could have two properties, `value` and `text`, and those properties could be used where it says `.val(option).text(option)`, to instead be something like  `.val(option.value).text(option.text)`.